# Dynamically added buttons to panel , click won't fire

Tags: asp.net

I feel I'm facing a stupid problem and that I'm missing a small thing somewhere but I really don't see it :/

I have a wizard step containing a panel.
I add dynamically to this panel buttons and assign an event handler to the click event of these buttons.

The code in the click event handler wont work and its kinda pissing me off as it seems simple and stupid but still not working and taking too much time.

Would be awesome if one of you guys would give it a look and maybe see what I didn't see.

PS : I'm not that familiar with ASP .NET

Here's ( part of ) the code :

the wizard step :

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="step1" runat="server" StepType="Complete" OnActivate="step1_Activate">
            <asp:Panel ID="panelID" runat="server" ScrollBars="Both" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" CssClass="bigButton" Text="<%$Resources: WebResources, CommonButtonBackText %>" OnClick="btnBack_Click" />
        </asp:WizardStep>
```

And here is code behind `step1_Activate` :

```
try
        {
            panelID.Controls.Clear();

            // Get list of asset dto for current user
            var userId = long.Parse(Session["ID"].ToString());

            var userDtos = presenter.DoSomething(userId );

            // Create buttons container

            foreach (var button in userDtos.Select(dtoProperty => new Button() { Text = dtoProperty.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }))
            {

                button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

                button.Click += delegate
                {
                    bossWiz.MoveTo(step2);
                };

                panelID.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message);
            bossWiz.MoveTo(stepError);
        }
```

Debugger inside the click never triggers !
And the view is just refreshed on the wizard step 1.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic controls must be re-created on every postback, [this Article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx) is a good link about how to persist dynamic controls and their state.

When you realize that the Page is just an instance of a class and a new instance is created for every request, you realize that your dynamic controls will not exist when you do a postback and you need to re-create them.

You should store the state required to re-create the controls into viewstate, then build your controls based on this inside [CreateChildControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols(v=vs.110).aspx) on every postback.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you recreate dynamic buttons on each postback
2. Make sure you assign different ID to each button (for example btn0, btn1, btn2, ...)